# Creating a training loop for a Conditional DCGAN, using the CelebA dataset and PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, dcgan

I've been working for the past 4 months with a partner on a machine learning project using the [CelebA dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/jessicali9530/celeba-dataset).

Our next step in the project is to create a Conditional DCGAN that would receive 40 labels for each class in the dataset, as either a 0 for a non-existing facial attribute and a 1 for an existing facial attribute, like this: [1, 0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 0] -> length of list is 40,

and generate from it a human face accordingly. So if the set of 40 labels matches a young male with sunglasses, we'll expect the generator to synthesize for us a young-male-with-sunglasses-ish persona (*with variation from generation to generation because we feed it random noise each time*).

I'm going to use Google Colab Pro's premium GPU option to train the model, if it matters.

I've didn't want to reinvent the wheel and begin working from scratch, so I copied some working code for a CelebA, image generating, non-conditional DCGAN from [this article](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html), and tried to tweak it to be a Conditional GAN.

I got stuck in the **training loop** section due to a tensor size mismatch.

```py
# Training Loop

# Lists to keep track of progress
img_list = []
G_losses = []
D_losses = []
iters = 0

print("Starting Training Loop...")
# For each epoch
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # For each batch in the dataloader
    for i, (real_cpu, conditions) in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
        ############################
        # (1) Update D network: maximize log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
        ###########################
        ## Train with all-real batch
        netD.zero_grad()

        # Format batch
        b_size = real_cpu.size(0)

        label = torch.full((b_size, 1, 1, 1), real_label, device=device, dtype=torch.float32)
        
        # Repeat the conditions tensor along the spatial dimensions
        conditions = conditions.view(-1, 40, 1, 1)
        conditions = conditions.repeat(1, 1, image_size, image_size)

        # Forward pass real batch through D
        output = netD(real_cpu.to(device), conditions.to(device))

        label = torch.full((b_size, 1, 1, 1), real_label, device=device, dtype=torch.float32)

        # Calculate loss on all-real batch
        errD_real = criterion(output, label)

        # Calculate gradients for D in backward pass
        errD_real.backward()
        D_x = output.mean().item()

        ## Train with all-fake batch
        # Generate batch of latent vectors
        noise = torch.randn(b_size, nz, 1, 1, device=device)

        # Generate fake image batch with G

        fake = netG(noise, conditions.to(device)) # <-- ERROR HERE
        label.fill_(fake_label)

        # Classify all fake batch with D
        output = netD(fake.detach(), conditions.to(device))
        # Calculate D's loss on the all-fake batch
        errD_fake = criterion(output, label)
        # Calculate the gradients for this batch, accumulated (summed) with previous gradients
        errD_fake.backward()
        D_G_z1 = output.mean().item()
        # Compute error of D as sum over the fake and the real batches
        errD = errD_real + errD_fake
        # Update D
        optimizerD.step()

        ############################
        # (2) Update G network: maximize log(D(G(z)))
        ###########################
        netG.zero_grad()
        label.fill_(real_label)  # fake labels are real for generator cost
        # Since we just updated D, perform another forward pass of all-fake batch through D
        output = netD(fake, conditions.to(device))
        # Calculate G's loss based on this output
        errG = criterion(output, label)
        # Calculate gradients for G
        errG.backward()
        D_G_z2 = output.mean().item()
        # Update G
        optimizerG.step()

        # Output training stats
        if i % 50 == 0:
          print('[%d/%d][%d/%d]\tLoss_D: %.4f\tLoss_G: %.4f\tD(x): %.4f\tD(G(z)): %.4f / %.4f'
              % (epoch, num_epochs, i, len(dataloader),
                 errD.item(), errG.item(), D_x, D_G_z1, D_G_z2))

        # Save Losses for plotting later
        G_losses.append(errG.item())
        D_losses.append(errD.item())

        # Check how the generator is doing by saving G's output on fixed_noise
        if (iters % 500 == 0) or ((epoch == num_epochs-1) and (i == len(dataloader)-1)):
          with torch.no_grad():
            fake = netG(fixed_noise).detach().cpu()
          img_list.append(vutils.make_grid(fake, padding=2, normalize=True))

    iters += 1
```

The error is in this line:

```py
fake = netG(noise, conditions.to(device))
```

When I try to concatenate the two tensors in the generator's forward function:

```py
def forward(self, input, label):
# Concatenate the input noise and label
    input = torch.cat((input, label), 1)
    return self.conv(input)
```

```
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 1 but got size 64 for tensor number 1 in the list.
```

since:

```py
noise.shape = torch.Size([64, 100, 1, 1])
```

and

```py
conditions.shape = torch.Size([64, 40, 64, 64])
```

I tried to reshape `conditions` with these lines, before feeding the generator with it as its second parameter:

```py
conditions = conditions.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
conditions = conditions.view(batch_size, 1, 1, 40)
```

which didn't work:

```
RuntimeError: shape '[64, 1, 1, 40]' is invalid for input of size 10485760
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/ideas on how to change the code. I really feel like I'm missing something really fundamental here that's preventing the training loop from working properly.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @СергейКох Thanks, however should I try and repost? This question is probably dead already...